# Draw line using storyboard animation windows phone

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1, scaletransform

I have a line in windows phone runtime app.

```
<Line x:Name="Line1" Height="178" Width="166" Stretch="Fill" StrokeDashArray="4,4" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" X1="100" Y1="150" X2="105" Y2="108" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
```

I want to animate this line so that its **length will start increasing** from *(X1,Y1)* and will increase till *(X2,Y2)*, to have a **line drawing effect**.

PS: I am using **Line** not Path.

Here is what I have done:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X2" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="101" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="102" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="103" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="104" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="105" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Line1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y2" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="120" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="110" />
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:1:0" Value="108" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Also Have tried *ScaleTransform* but does not meet my expectations.

Any solution to this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a `RectangleGeometry` `Clip` region on the `Line`, apply a `Transform` to the geometry, set the rotation on the transform to correspond to the line orientation, the `Rect` on the geometry to correspond to line length/thickness and animate the scale of the `Transform` from 0 to 1.

The should get you a line that doesn't move while it's drawing and a smooth animation.

Comment: thanks for such a nice explanation!! worked great! +one for that.